# i don't know why the result is like this? i expected 15 50 5

Tags: c++

I don't know why the result is like this? I expected 15 50 5.
Could anybody help me understand the result

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int f(int &a, int &b)
{
    int m = a;
    int n = b;
    a = a*b;
    b = a / b;
    return n + m;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 5;
    cout << f(x, y) << " " << x << " " << y;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
//why is the result like this?
```

Comment: Result is like what?

Comment: I don't know what you get, but expected is: 15 50 10

Comment: the result that vs 2015 gets me is 15 10 5.

Comment: @Kasra Follow the link.

Comment: The problem is that `f(x, y)` updates `x` and `y`. We don't know if the output shows the old or the new values. That is unspecified.

Comment: apparently the output shows the new values.because the function is called by refrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Just call your function like this:

  ```
  int a = f(x, y);
  cout << a << " " << x << " " << y;
  ```

Comment: amazing.it works.thank you a lot.but what is the reason???

Comment: I cannot post an answer anymore, so no full code sorry, but if you check the disassembly , first Y gets fed to the stream, then , X gets fed then it calls f, and feeds the result.
http://s30.postimg.org/8ke0jt08h/disass.jpg

This is on VS2015

Comment: because order of evaluation is unspecified.May be from left-to-right or right-to-left.

Comment: i think you're right.that was really kind of you